# Can you make a universal function for multiple objects?

Tags: python, variables

I'm making a chess game, and I have to restate the same set of rules every time I make a pawn, is there any way to make this easier. Here is the script i have to restate every time.

```
elif spacesdirection == "DR":
               if bpawn8xpos - 1 == wpawn1xpos and bpawn8ypos - 1 == wpawn1ypos:
                   bpawn8xpos -= 1
                   bpawn8ypos -= 1
                   print("wpawn1 is dead!")
                   wpawn1a = "dead"
                   move += 1
                   start()
```

Is there any good way do this for multiple pawns such as, bpawn7, wpawn3, etc.

Comment: btw. this is python

Comment: Whait is `restate`? It is not clear what do you want to improve/change.

Comment: If you make the pawn a class, then you can just make a function that takes the pawn class as a parameter and then modifies variables within the class.

Comment: @AGNGazer In this chess game I have multiple pawns and i was wondering if there would be an easier way to make this for multiple pawns in one function every pawn uses, instead of copy and pasting it in for every pawn

Comment: @funnyman2732 Generally, while coding, you should never have to copy and paste code. You should look into object oriented programming, and classes. Doing so would help you achieve your goal here, and help you out a lot in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use lists instead of numbered variables, and at least put repeating code inside helper functions.
It would be better to define classes representing each piece, and they would store the relevant procedures.

Comment: Does this answer their original question?

Comment: @ifconfig Well the question is not phrased using standard programming terms (universal, restate, 'make a'...) so to my interpretation it does.